# How can i get access to the Contacts API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am a developer tasked with an investigation about the LinkedIn APIs. More specifically, I need to be able to get information on a user's connections and I think that the Contacts API would be a good match, since it retrieves a logged-in user's connections and I currently have no means to access the Connections API. The problem is I do not know how to get access to it, as it is not clear enough in the documentation I have read thus far.

I have checked the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/contacts-api) and several posts in Stack Overflow about the topic, but I have not been able to find the answer I have been looking for. I have also read through other resources, such as the API Terms of Use and many other forum posts, but with the same result.

On the API documentation, all it says is that "The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements.", however I do not understand where I should apply for approval, as the Contacts API does not seem to be under any of the options I can apply to. Is it possible to apply for it at all?

Thanks in advance